# Пустая страница при обращении к API Angular

Tags: javascript, angular2

Обращаюсь к локальному Web Api по адресу http://localhost:50806/api/Users. Он возвращает:

```
[
     {"UserId":1,"Name":"O. Cole"},
     {"UserId":2,"Name":"J. Shane"},
     {"UserId":3,"Name":"V. Petrov"},
     {"UserId":4,"Name":"M. Popov"}
]
```

В папке app есть файл user.ts

```
export class User{
    UserId: number;
    Name: string;
}
```

Файл обращения к api:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService{

    Url = 'http://localhost:50806/';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }

    getUsers(){
        return this.http.get(this.Url + 'api/Users');
    }
}
```

Файл компонента:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService} from './http.service';
import {User} from './user';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<ul>
                <li *ngFor="let user of users">
                <p>Имя пользователя: {{user?.Name}}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>`,
    providers: [HttpService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

    users: User[];

    constructor(private httpService: HttpService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.httpService.getUsers().subscribe((data: User[]) => this.users=data);
    }
}
```

Страница пуста и нет ошибок в консоле, подскажите что не так?

Update! Основной модуль:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

import { HttpClientModule }   from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Зачем вы в Providers добавили HttpService?

Comment: @ШерзодЁров делал по гайду на сайте. Перед этим обращались к серверу в компоненте.

Comment: Странно... вы в основой модуль HttpClientMOdule добавили? В компоненте в Providers он не нужен. Вы через конструктор инжектите его.

Comment: @ШерзодЁров Обновил вопрос, добавил основной модуль.

Comment: в Imports добавьте HttpClientModule

Comment: @ШерзодЁров ошибка "Argument of type 'User[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
  Property 'UserId' is missing in type 'User[]'."

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73902/discussion-between-lada-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл модуля у вас должен выглядеть примерно так

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpService} from './app.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Вы импортировали HttpClientModule, но не добавили в файл импорта. 
2. Во-вторых, вы должны убедится, что данные приходят.
3. В сервисе кое что поправил

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {User} from './user';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  Url = 'ваш URL';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.Url);
  }
}
```

Обратите внимание где находится ваш файл User.ts.

4. файл компонента в файле компонента поменяйте

   ngOnInit(){
   this.httpService.getUsers().subscribe((data) => this.users=data);
   }